# Qmail SMTP receiver always delays by 66 seconds

Tags: smtp, greylisting, qmail

I am currently struggling with a problem in my qmail setup, which seems to delay my smtp receiver everytime for 66 seconds. This is for most remote hosts fine, but some seem to reach their timeout and do not deliver the mail.

I am running qmail with jgreylist and the delay seem to happen between the initial connection and jgreylist.

```
2018-08-16 08:13:18.143940500 tcpserver: status: 2/30
2018-08-16 08:13:18.144214500 tcpserver: pid 989 from 209.85.213.41
2018-08-16 08:13:18.145110500 tcpserver: ok 989    
mail.klement.com:138.201.24.116:25 mail-vk0-f41.google.com:209.85.213.41::36018
2018-08-16 08:14:24.394795500 jgreylist[989]: 209.85.213.41: OK known
2018-08-16 08:14:25.026792500 qmail-smtpd[989]: MFCHECK pass [209.85.213.41] gmail.com
2018-08-16 08:14:25.028190500 qmail-smtpd[989]: Received-SPF: pass (mail.klm.com: SPF record at _netblocks.google.com designates 209.85.213.41 as permitted sender)
2018-08-16 08:14:25.028369500 qmail-smtpd[989]: MAIL FROM:<d.klm@gmail.com>
2018-08-16 08:14:25.028566500 qmail-smtpd[989]: RCPT TO:<d@klm.com>
2018-08-16 08:14:25.028718500 qmail-smtpd[989]: validrcptto [209.85.213.41] trying: d@klm.com
2018-08-16 08:14:25.028880500 qmail-smtpd[989]: validrcptto [209.85.213.41] found: d@klm.com
2018-08-16 08:14:25.485688500 tcpserver: end 989 status 0
```

I don't have any delay setup in the config.

Here are my values:

```
JGREYLIST_NOREV=1
JGREYLIST_BY_IP=0
JGREYLIST_HOLDTIME=120
JGREYLIST_LOG=1
JGREYLIST_LOG_PID=1
JGREYLIST_LOG_SMTP=0
JGREYLIST_TIMEOUT=120
JGREYLIST_LIMIT=0

SMTPGREETING="$LOCAL NO UCE"
SMTPD_GREETDELAY=0
#GREETDELAY=5
#DROP_PRE_GREET=1
DENY_TLS=0
MFCHECK=3
```

I start tcpserver like this.

```
tcpserver -vR -l mail.klm.com -c 30 -u 162 -g 161 -x /var/qmail/service/smtpd-receiver/tcp.cdb 128.111.xxx.xxx 25 rblsmtpd -t0 -r ix.dnsbl.manitu.net -r zen.spamhaus.org -r dnsbl.njabl.org -r bl.spamcop.net jgreylist /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd
```

Everything that speeds this up is more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using whitelisting on jgreylist, I figured out that the problem still existed, so the problem must have been somewhere else and it was.

The delay has been caused due to an inactive RBL server in the tcpserver command. 
tcpserver tried checking till it timed out (60 secs).

So make sure that all RBL servers are active and work.